# How to use VC++ compiler flags to specify enum size

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, enums, c++03

I have a C++ code base which compiles on two platforms, one of them is Visual C++ 2013. 
The second platform supports C++03 (and not C++11). The enum size implementation in the second platform's compiler is to use the minimal needed size.
VC++ implementation is to use 4 bytes, even if they're not needed.

I'd like to make VC++ compile the enums as minimal size as well, without modifying the code. The other compiler, for example, does not compile this:

```
enum MyEnum : unsigned char {};
```

I searched, but could not find compiler flags to support this.
Do they exist?

Comment: This has terrible idea written all over it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I can imagine how without knowing any of the context, requirements or rational you would feel you have enough data to conclude that. What does it have to do with the quality of the question itself?

Comment: Yes, I can conclude that this has the potential to break a good number of things. Changing the size of the `enum` at a global scope affects everything. This means the definition of the `enum` _changes_ between what your code expects and the original code expects. If you're building against source code the problems are less apparent if you're simply linking to the library bad things an happen. If there is an expectation of size any code that rely on it will likely break. Expect to review the usage of _all_ `enum` types and then re-review anytime you update to newer libraries.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for your comments. I am fully aware of these. My usage is not for production code but for analyzing embedded memory dumps. All the code is internal to my team. No libraries are involved. And if the enum size can be done not in global scope but on the file level it will be even better, but if global scope is what the compiler flags can do, so be it. I didn't see, however, any suggestion on how to do this at the compiler level.

Answer (score 2):

C++03 must understand explicit type for enum constants:

```
enum Enumeration 
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  : unsigned char
#endif
{
   ONE = unsigned char(1), // storage type for enum is unsigned char
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I'd like to avoid explicitly stating for each enum its required type, both because of the extra work and the potential errors - if I add a large value to an enum it can break.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion although you could do something like `#define ENUM_SIZE : unsigned char` and then `enum Enumeration ENUM_SIZE { };`